# Cannot add textbox with button click in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, html-table

I want to add text box in table > td where checkbox is checked, but not working. How can I do this? I'm new to jQuery.

This is my code html:

```
<table id="list_lab" class="checkbox-inline">
<tr>
    <td><input id="list_lab_0" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$0" checked="checked" value="Electrolyte (Lab)"><label for="list_lab_0">Electrolyte (Lab)</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="list_lab_1" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$1" checked="checked" value="Creatinine (plus eGFR)"><label for="list_lab_1">Creatinine (plus eGFR)</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="list_lab_2" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$2" value="Blood Urea Nitrogen"><label for="list_lab_2">Blood Urea Nitrogen</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="list_lab_3" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$3" value="Complete Blood Count"><label for="list_lab_3">Complete Blood Count</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="list_lab_4" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$4" value="Dengue NS1 Ag"><label for="list_lab_4">Dengue NS1 Ag</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="list_lab_5" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$5" value="Influenza A/B A/(H1N1) Screening"><label for="list_lab_5">Influenza A/B A/(H1N1) Screening</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="list_lab_6" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$6" value="Urine Exam"><label for="list_lab_6">Urine Exam</label></td>
</tr>
```

And this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#btn_check').click(function () {
        var length = 0;
        $('#list_lab').find('tr').each(function(){
            var row = $(this);
            if(row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
                $('#list_lab').find(td).append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="txt_row '" + length + "'" />')
            }
            length++;
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working code.  Click the button below to run it.

This line:

```
$('#list_lab').find(td).append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="txt_row '" + length + "'" />')
```

should have been:

```
$('#list_lab').find('td').append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="txt_row_"' + length + '" />');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function create_inputs() {
    var length = 0;
    $('#list_lab').find('tr').each(function() {
      var row = $(this);
      if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        // first check if you've already added an input to this row
        if ($(this).find('input[type="text"]').length == 0) {
          $(this).find('td').append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="txt_row_"' + length + '" />');
        }
      } else {
        // if this is not checked, then remove any inputs that you might have added
        $(this).find('input[type="text"]').remove();
      }
      length++;
    });

  }

  // set this to run whenever you click a checkbox
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    create_inputs();
  });
  
  // and also run once when you first load
  create_inputs();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="list_lab" class="checkbox-inline">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="list_lab_0" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$0" checked="checked" value="Electrolyte (Lab)">
      <label for="list_lab_0">Electrolyte (Lab)</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="list_lab_1" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$1" checked="checked" value="Creatinine (plus eGFR)">
      <label for="list_lab_1">Creatinine (plus eGFR)</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="list_lab_2" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$2" value="Blood Urea Nitrogen">
      <label for="list_lab_2">Blood Urea Nitrogen</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="list_lab_3" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$3" value="Complete Blood Count">
      <label for="list_lab_3">Complete Blood Count</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="list_lab_4" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$4" value="Dengue NS1 Ag">
      <label for="list_lab_4">Dengue NS1 Ag</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="list_lab_5" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$5" value="Influenza A/B A/(H1N1) Screening">
      <label for="list_lab_5">Influenza A/B A/(H1N1) Screening</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="list_lab_6" type="checkbox" name="list_lab$6" value="Urine Exam">
      <label for="list_lab_6">Urine Exam</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btn_check">click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @manishie. But the result is not be like in my mine.I want to create 1 textbox where input type checkbox is checked .How can i do ?

Comment: i want it to show like When i click check box then then box is create new label on this input type checkbox

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand

Comment: i want to say if input type checkbox is check it will create textbox like your code then if i click other checkbox ,it will create textbox near the checkbox where i click.Are you understand me ?

Comment: get function click in button out